# iOS7 apps supporting older versions?

Tags: ios, ios7, app-store

Of all the iOS7 apps I have seen, none of them support the earlier versions (6.1 or earlier)

I wanted to know if my apps supports both, iOS6 and iOS7, will my app be rejected?

Comment: its fine if your app supports ios6 and ios7 infact many peoples are making updates to support both the platforms

Answer (score 2):

No. You can support iOS 6 and 7. Just target the latest SDK and set your deployment target to iOS6. If you use APIs that are only available in iOS 7 then you need to check to make sure they exist (`respondsToSelector:`) prior to calling them or your app will crash on iOS 6, though.

Comment: I would suggest to not set the baseSDK to 6 but the Deployment Target.

Comment: thanks. I wanted to confirm that if I support both, will apple reject the app? As one targets flat-UI and the other, skeuomorphism.

Comment: No, they will not reject the app for supporting both

Answer (score 1):

**1)** No your app is not going to be rejected.

**2)** You can upload your app with iOS 6 support only.

**3)** You can upload your app with both (iOS6/iOS7) Supported With setting deployment target 6.1 or whatever you want.

**4)** If you want to upload app with both iOS 6 and 7 , you have to make some changes in UI because in iOS 7 some UI is going to changed like,Switch,Tabbar,statusbar. So make changes in it.

**5)** For more information regarding iOS 7 UI https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/design/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013289

**6)** For more information regarding integrate iOS 6/7 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html